# how to redirect routing with .htacces

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, redirect, routes

My problem is i bought a shity hosting and now i can not set my own config.
I need to do it by .htaccess file.
Here is what i manage to do:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Project/web/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Project/web/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ Project/web/app.php [L]
```

I know that this will not work with some website software like mine. and I also need to modify the $base_url, $live_site or other configuration settings in those to finish the process.

To make it all clear with this settings when i enter my domain i start from subdirectory i choose. but when i try to go to another page its return 404 error.

I have an idea how to make it work, its need to redirect also routing 
so for example `www.domain.com/page` need to be redirected to `www.domain.com/Project/web/page` if anyone know how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed symfony on a shared hosting service one time.

That's what I had to do to make Symfony work :

in the public directory there is the structure of the project :

```
/app
/src
/vendor
/web/.htaccess
/.htaccess
```

In /.htaccess I wrote :

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 5_3
SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /web

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|swf|txt|pdf|doc|docx|mp3|svg)$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [QSA,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/app.php/$1 [QSA,L]
 </IfModule>
```

in /web/.htaccess I wrote :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

That's all...

Comment: It isnt working for me
i have that structure you mention in one more folder called project
like this `public directory/Project/...`
and in public directory i did .htacces like this:
`SetEnv PHP_VER 5_4
SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase Project/web

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|swf|txt|pdf|doc|docx|mp3|svg)$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [QSA,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ Project/web/app.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: page: `Internal Server Error`
and from log `[Thu Nov 21 18:13:51 2013] [alert] [client 156.13.234.244] /public_html/.htaccess: RewriteBase: argument is not a valid URL`

Comment: yes, the first / is missing in your file : RewriteBase /Project/web

Comment: ok it's fixed by now:
but in my `/Project/` i have also a .htacces file with `deny from all` Its not allowed to be there ?
`[Thu Nov 21 20:08:41 2013] [error] [client 156.13.234.244] client denied by server configuration: /home/sl129581/public_html/Project/web/Project`. becouse if i delate it it works

Comment: I'm not sure, but if you deny to all "/Project/" I think your users can't access "/Project/web"... Could you remove it ? Security is recursive

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the end of your last comment. Glad it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the PHP header function?

```
<?php header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); exit; ?>
```

[PHP: header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)